# Section by Section scrolling Web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a new website for my Android game, and i was surfing the web looking for some inspiration, and I came by this website: [Fantasy.co](http://fantasy.co)

does anyone knows what javascript library is used there?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Webslides](https://webslides.tv/)

Github Link : https://github.com/jlantunez/webslides/

It is easy to implement and does exactly what you are expecting.